# SQLite csv import Number of Rows per page decreased to 684

Tags: sqlite, csv-import

When trying to import a.csv file into a SQLite table with 219 columns and 93042 rows, received the following error:
"[19:51:23] Number of rows per page was decreased to 684 due to number of columns (219) in the data view."
Is SQLite capable of handling such a large table?
By the way, it appears certain fields have mixed datatypes and I selected "Ignore Errors" while importing as I was just doing a test for a data cleaning process I am working on.
I am new to SQLite and would appreciate any help on this subject.
Thanks,

Comment: This looks more like a warning than an error. Was your data imported, or not?

Comment: Thanks so much for reviewing my question. Unfortunately the data was not imported. I even did a simple select * query and no records were shown.